# Setting ClickListener from the Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, clicklistener

Having problems to set ClickListener from Layout

Inside my layout:

```
<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/VimeoButton" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/vimeo_icon"
    android:onClick="OpenVimeo"
>
```

And in the main class (an activity):

```
public void OpenVimeo(View v)
    {

        Intent myIntent;
        Log.i(tag,"Inside");
        myIntent=new Intent (AndroidRSS.this,Video.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
```

But seems not to handle click events.

Comment: sorry cant understand ur que.?whr you put clicklistener and on which you put.cant understand

Comment: Are you sure you're running the code you think you're running? Try cleaning and rebuilding.

Answer (score 2):

When we give onClick inside layout, no need to give switch case inside your

```
public void OpenVimeo(View v)
```

OpenVimeo method is given inside onClick for the ImageButton. So only on clicking the ImageButton the code inside the method will work.

And regarding the solution...

Instead of this ImageButton if you give it as a normal button it will work. Instead of

```
android:src=""
```

give `android:background=""` for button.

If you still want to use ImageButton, add `android:clickable="true"` to your ImageButton tag and see. I think it may work. Please give a try and just reply if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

your code is right but may be u forgot add activity in android.manifeast

so add activity to android.manifeast

Answer (score -3):

I think you forgot about switch... 
public void OpenVimeo(View v)
    {
       //first 
       switch(v) {
       case VimeoButton:

```
    Intent myIntent;
    Log.i(tag,"Inside");
    myIntent=new Intent (AndroidRSS.this,Video.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
  }
```

//another casesss..
    }

Comment: Why would you need a switch here?

Comment: Switch is not needed because he handles the event exclusively from the layout file.

Comment: To  Falmarri , theresia  How app will knew that the user clicked on 'VimeoButton'..??? Without switch it will not work!! I'll bring a solution of this a little later when i'll be free